# Which tool to crop a portion of the screen?

Tags: screenshot

I can see how to use Gimp to crop part of an image in a image file, but I want to crop a portion of the screen. How do you do that?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

#### On Gnome Shell (17.10+)

To use the built-in `gnome-screenshot` capability (by default):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to copy a screenshot of the whole desktop.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to copy a screenshot of the current active window.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to copy a screenshot of an area you select with your mouse.
- <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to save a screenshot of the whole desktop at `/home/user/Pictures`.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to save a screenshot of the current active window at `/home/user/Pictures`.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to save a screenshot of an area you select with your mouse at `/home/user/Pictures`.

[image: screenshot]

#### On Unity

To use the built-in `Screenshot` capability:

- <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to copy a screenshot of the whole desktop.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to copy a screenshot of the current active window.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to copy a screenshot of an area you select with your mouse.

Comment: Where is this cropped portion getting saved? Or if it's just on my clipboard, how do I save it?

Comment: For me, the screenshot was copied to the clipboard and I was able to paste it into the chat where I needed it without any problems. Alternatively, you could create a new Google Docs file and paste the screenshot there. Then you can download it as a PDF for example.

Comment: Nowadays this still working

Answer (score 33):

**Applications > Accessories > Take Screenshot**... Select area to grab.

[image: Take Screenshot option in Accessories in Applications menu]

Comment: Thank you for answering my basic question. I would have expected this to be in the "Graphics" menu with other image manipulations tools.

Answer (score 24):

**Method 1:**

- Go to **Applications > Accessories > Take Screenshot**

  [image: Take Screenshot dialog]
- Now you can select the portion of a screen.

**Method 2:**

**Update**: Shutter [got removed from Debian/*Ubuntu](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/shutter) repos because [it uses deprecated Perl modules](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=870418).

- If you use shutter, **Applications > Accessories > Shutter**
- Open it and click selection in the top of the screen.

  [image: Selection option in top left of window]
- Now you can select the portion of the screen.

**Method 3:**

- Take a screenshot of a whole desktop by hitting printscreen.
- Open the screenshot using GIMP.
- Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to crop the portion.

Comment: This answer was perfect at the time it was written. But now this function is built in. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/72386/print-screen-key-can-no-longer-select-a-region-to-capture. So @konrad's answer should be used NOW.

Answer (score 10):

### [Flameshot](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot)

I know this is a 10 year old question but I didn't like any of the options posted. I really like [Flameshot](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot). It's a one-stop shop with nice keyboard shortcuts. Simply `apt install flameshot`.

[image: Flameshot animated usage]

Shutter got removed from Debian/*buntu repos because it uses deprecated Perl modules. Gnome- and Mate-screenshot are too basic.

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 8):

Well if you mean pressing the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> button and *then* cropping with a console tool, then you have [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) to do that (by installing the imagemagick tools)

If you want to take a picture of a certain windows, select the window a leave <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed while pressing the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key.

Using Compiz, you can zoom to an area using the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and scrolling inwards, then <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.

In KDE you have `ksnapshot` which gives many abilities, one including taking a snapshot of a region.

Comment: :) "mogrify"... It sounded like a slang term, but I just found out its an actual **Linux command**.. (and here is the word's [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=mogrify&searchmode=none) if you're interested... and I lke the compiz idea.. thanks

Answer (score 8):

[Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) is also a great capturing application and it can crop a portion of the screen automatically.

Answer (score 7):

With imagemagick installed, you can type:

```
import filename.png
```

at the command prompt. It will give you a cross-hairs you can use to draw a rectangle on the screen which it will then capture.

(`filename.png` can be any graphics format.)

Answer (score 6):

[scrot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/scrot)

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
```

scrot (SCReen shOT) is a simple commandline screen capture utility that uses imlib2 to grab and save images. Multiple image formats are supported through imlib2's dynamic saver modules.

Run: `scrot -s`

[image: -s, --select : Interactively select a window or rectangle with the mouse.]

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add that you can now type <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>printscreen</kbd> to select an area to print.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use GIMP to capture only part of a shot of the display screen, then use File - Acquire - Screenshot - Select region to grab - Snap.  Left-click on the screen, hold button down, drag to form a rectangle, and release the mouse button to capture an image of the selected portion of the screen.

Note that different versions of GIMP use different command menu sequences, e.g. "Acquire" may be labelled "Create".

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers worked for me in Linux mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit,

The following thing in the screenshot worked for me,

[image]

Adding steps that I followed as suggested by Tshilidzi Mudau,

1. Created a script `gnome_area_screenshot.sh`, contents of which are as follows,

> ```
> #! /bin/sh
>
> sleep 0.125
> gnome-screenshot --area
> ```

2. Opened Keyboard settings from settings menu.
3. Click on Shortcuts tab.
4. Click on Add Custom Shortcuts present at the bottom panel.
5. Give name as 'Area Screenshot' (or anything you wish to).
6. And Command as /gnome_area_screenshot.sh.
7. In the Keyboard Shortcuts select 'Area Screenshot' and in the Keyboard bindings Double click and give any key combination which you wish to give as keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Hi @Gokul Kulkarni,  maybe put the steps you followed and the code/commands you ran instead of screenshots?

Comment: @Tshilidzi Mudau updated the answer.

Comment: Looking good :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNOME, the [imgur screenshot uploader](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/683/imgur-screenshot-uploader/) is pretty great. It sits in the top bar. It gives you the option to drag and select an area, select a window, or select a desktop to screenshot. It'll automatically upload the screenshot and give you the link to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use shortcuts.

1. Open system-keyboard-Shortcuts

   [image: in Settings]
2. Click **Custom Shortcuts**
3. Click the button <kbd>+</kbd> on the right

   [image: adding custom shortcut option]
4. Add a name such as "crop", and add the following line (assuming you are using gnome)

   ```
    gnome-screenshot -a
   ```

   [image: adding shortcut popup dialog]
5. Click <kbd>add</kbd>
6. Click "Disable" && set a shortcut as you wish
7. Pictures would automatically saved in the folder **Pictures**

   [image: Sample contents of Pictures]

Answer (score -1):

I write a bash simulate key shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> in OSX for fast crop screen.
What make this shortcut useful because it reduce the number of step to create a crop image. You just need call Ctrl+Shift+4 and drag, file cropped auto save with name format by time created, no popup, typing name etc needed.

1. add key shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> in Custom key shortcut. Command link to your bash (eg: `/home/nickfarrow/bin/scrot.sh`)
2. Install scrot tool (similar import tool in imagemagick)
3. add bash to crop screen using `scrot` or `import` (need imagemagick):
   like:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash
   DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S")
   scrot -s ~/bin/crop/$DATE.png
   ```

`~/bin/crop` is the folder store crop image.

(Sorry for my English)
Hope this help.