# Snipping tool in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: screenshot, shutter

I searched for any type of snipping tool in ubuntu. I found Shutter & installed it. But my Ubuntu launcher didn't show its icon.

When I launch Shutter from terminal, my PC run slow & terminal showed hundreds of warnings. Is there any other snipping tool (Without Shutter) for Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: There is a screenshot tool installed by default in Ubuntu. Search that in Dash

Comment: see this:
[Which tool to crop a portion of the screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18867/which-tool-to-crop-a-portion-of-the-screen?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: @koni_raid `ctrl+shift+PrntScr` is amazing.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Have a look at Screenshot. You can find it in Ubuntu Software.

http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-screenshot

Good luck!

Comment: This is preinstalled on Ubuntu. You don't need to search it or install. Its also comes linked to several shortcuts such as Shift+PrntScrn

Comment: After taking one screenshot, how do you take another one without closing the program and re-opening? 16.04.

Comment: @user1271772 There is no option as such. You need to reopen it. I have added it in my Panel which makes it easier for reuse.

Comment: @Anand: seems like a very poorly designed software.

Comment: No need to install anything or reopen a program ... just press `shift + PrntScr` and you can then select the area you want to snip.

Pressing `shift+PrintScr` saves the snippet in your Pictures folder. Pressing `ctrl+shift+PrintScr` copies the snippet to your clipboard

Answer (score 160):

No need to install any other app or repo, just go with the defaults. Thank God for Ubuntu 16.04, it tries to get everything to work for users. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> keys together.

Your mouse will change to a cross-like pointer. Hold down your left-click key on the mouse and drag. It saves screenshot image to Pictures directory. To copy to Clipboard, use <kbd>Ctrl></kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>. Have fun.

This uses `gnome-screenshot` under the hood. You can change the keyboard shortcut via the regular keyboard settings.

Comment: @skrat But then this option doesn't gives us the feasibility to select any region and take a snap of it. I guess, this is why it is not at the top.

Comment: @Anand It sure does. Pressing CTRL + SHIFT + PRTSCN changes mouse cursor to a cross. With it, you can select the snipping region. That copies the selected region to clipboard - if you want it saved in "pictures" folder, simply use SHIFT + PRTSCN.

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu. Maybe that's the reason why I am not able to perform the same activity.

Comment: what Ubuntu are you using? @Anand
16 or 18 ?

Comment: This goes to clipboard for me by default and I can paste into slack which triggers an upload. Scratched my noodle on this for a minute before learning that.

Comment: this removes focus (e.g. closes select fields in the browser). any tool where you can capture the screen as is?

Comment: Where does it put it? I don't have a Pictures directory.

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to install any apps. By default, the Screenshot app is installed in Ubuntu 16.04. Just go to Accessories, and in Accessories find Screenshot.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer.

Comment: @karel This is not a duplicate of the accepted answer. [That answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/828773/22949) says to install Screenshot using the Ubuntu Software utility. This answer says that it is already installed and can be found in Accessories.

Comment: Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy commented below the accepted answer that "This is preinstalled on Ubuntu." so there's no need for a separate answer. In fact this answer could have been converted into a comment below the accepted answer, except that there already is one there.

Answer (score 3):

Installation process:

https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/02/snipping-tool-ubuntu-shutter.html

After following the above installation process, open the image to be edited and right click on it .
Click on open with and then on shutter . After that enjoy editing images using shutter and save them.

Answer (score 0):

Give screencloud a try. It sits in the panel as an indicator and it also has some nice annotating features you can use after the shot is taken. The installation instructions can be located [here on the screencloud site](https://screencloud.net/). For 16.04:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/screencloud.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screencloud
```

if needed, to add the release key:

```
wget -nv http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:olav-st/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key -O Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
sudo apt-get update
```